# Number Expected, Got Boolean

Tags: dynamic, lua, scoping

When I run this code, I get an error message that looks like this:

```
Runtime Error:
AI.lua:7: bad argument #2 to 'getlocal' (number      
expected, got boolean)
```

What can I do to resolve this? I need the Boolean value.

```
Anything = not nil
Nothing = not Anything
Everything = Anything and not Nothing
Overtaking = Anything and Nothing
God = Everything and Overtaking
Divinity = God and not not God
Better = debug.getlocal(1, Divinity)
x = ""
repeat
   i = 32
   repeat
      i = i + 1
      a = string.char(i)
      if Better == true then
          x = x .. a
      else x = x
      end
   until (i == 126)
until (x == x .. "")
print (x)
```

Comment: I cannot see ```getlocal``` function in your code.

Comment: Oops! Here's the codes latest edition.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `getlocal` requires an integer as the second argument and you passing boolean, so it won't work for you. Second, getlocal returns the local variables declared in a certain scope, so that really depends on what your'e trying to do here. I cannot see any locals in your code, so using getlocal won't get you anywhere.

Take a look at [getlocal usage](https://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.1.html).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to separate the addition to the Boolean values Divinity provides.